# Why last element is not compared in List using zip() in python?

Tags: python

I am using build-in function zip() to compare 2 element in List.

```
     myList =[11,12,93,14,15,45,56,67,78,11]
        z = 0;
        final = 0 ;
        for x, y in zip(myList, myList[1:]):
            if  x > y :
                z = x

            if  (final<x):
                final = x;
        print final;
```

For this code I get valid answer as: 93

Now if I add another element in last index as 333

```
myList =[11,12,93,14,15,45,56,67,78,11,333]
z = 0;
final = 0 ;
for x, y in zip(myList, myList[1:]):
    if  x > y :
        z = x

    if  (final<x):
        final = x;
print final;
```

I get still get output as :93 , but the correct answer in 333.

Can someone explain the logic as where I am wrong.

Comment: `zip` will truncate the longer list, there's nothing to compare `333` to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`zip` stops at the end of its shortest argument. `myList[1:]` is always one shorter than `myList` (provided the list isn't empty), and so the last pair you get from `zip` is `x,y = 11,333`:

```
>>> myList =[11,12,93,14,15,45,56,67,78,11,333]
>>> pairs = zip(myList, myList[1:])
>>> list(pairs)[-1]
(11, 333)
```

But you only ever assign `final` and `z` to the current value of `x`, which can never be the last element. You could add a phantom element to the end of the list that can't trigger the conditions: you're using mixed greater and lesser comparisons, so your best option is the special value "not a number" `float('nan')`, which is neither bigger nor smaller than any number (all comparisons return `False`). For the special case of pairs, you can put the dummy element in like this since the second argument is known to be exactly one element shorter than the longer one:

```
>>> pairs = zip(myList, myList[1:]+[float('nan')])
>>> list(pairs)[-1]
(333, nan)
```

But for a more general solution, you will want to use `zip_longest` from itertools, which effectively pads the end of the shorter arguments like this until they are the length of the longest one:

```
>>> pairs = it.zip_longest(myList, myList[1:], fillvalue=float('nan'))
>>> list(pairs)[-1]
(333, nan)
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [itertools.izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest), as you are attempting to zip together iterables that are different in length. `izip_longest` will allow you to add a fill value for the iterables that are shorter than the longest one.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is because `zip` has length equal to the shortest sequence. Note that in the first case your list is of even length (so all pairs are returned), but in the second, it's odd, so you don't get the last one. If you wanted different behavior, take a look at `itertools.izip_longest`.

Comment: If there is a List suppose myList =[11,12,93,14,15,45,56,67,78,11], zip() function make  comparison as 11 to 12 , 12 to 93 , 93 to 14 .... Am I right?